# How do I call a javascript function of a parent webview in a child webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm developing a web page with html/css/javascript that will open in a webview.
I'm planning to do the following.

1. Use `window.open` in a webview(webview1) to open another webview(webview2).
2. Call webview1's javascript function from webview2 (using window.opener in webview2)
3. Close webview2.

I'd like to do the above using `window.open` and `window.opener`.

https://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window

But I heard `window.open` and `window.opener` doesn't work in webview in default settings and OnCreateWindow has to be overriden in order for `window.open` to work.
What exactly should I do when I override OnCreateWindow?

I have little knowledge in Android development and I as a web developer have to communicate with Android developer to make things work.

Thanks for your help!